# TeeChart On Mouse Over a series display a user define Image

Tags: activex, teechart

My requirement is I want to display a Image box when a user perform a mouse over on a bar in the chart. Currently in mouse over we are displaying the text such as label, Percentage etc can we display Image as well.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hidden Rectangle tool to show the desired image and use the provided events to change its visibility, position, or the image loaded.
Ie, using `OnMouseEnterSeries`/`OnMouseLeaveSeries`, but the same could be done with `OnMouseMove` event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False

  TChart1.AddSeries scBar
  TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues

  TChart1.Tools.Add tcMarksTip

  TChart1.Tools.Add tcRectangle
  TChart1.Tools.Items(1).Active = False
  TChart1.Tools.Items(1).asRectangle.AllowDrag = False
  TChart1.Tools.Items(1).asRectangle.AllowResize = False
  TChart1.Tools.Items(1).asRectangle.Shape.Transparency = 0
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnMouseEnterSeries(ByVal SeriesIndex As Long)
  ValueIndex = TChart1.Series(SeriesIndex).Clicked(TChart1.MousePosition.X, TChart1.MousePosition.Y)
  If ValueIndex = 2 Then
    TChart1.Tools.Items(1).Active = True
    TChart1.Tools.Items(1).asRectangle.Shape.Picture.LoadImage "C:\tmp\ImageForValueIndex2.png"
    TChart1.Tools.Items(1).asRectangle.Left = TChart1.MousePosition.X
    TChart1.Tools.Items(1).asRectangle.Top = TChart1.MousePosition.Y
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnMouseLeaveSeries(ByVal SeriesIndex As Long)
  TChart1.Tools.Items(1).Active = False
End Sub
```

---

**Edit**:

As noticed in the [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547284/teechart-on-mouse-over-a-series-display-a-user-define-image/25549763#comment39988232_25549763), TeeChart VCL v2014.11 introduced `SystemHints` property as explained [here](http://www.steema.com/linkIn/WhatsNewVCL):

> MarksTip tool new property SystemHints (boolean default True in VCL,
>   False in Firemonkey). When False, a normal TeeShape object is used to
>   paint the tiptool instead of using the VCL system mechanism.
>
> ```
> ChartTool3.SystemHints := False;
> ChartTool3.Format.Font.Size:=14;
> ```
>
> The only disadvantadge compared to system hints is the shape cannot be
>   displayed outside the chart bounds.
>
> When SystemHints is False, the new Format property (of type TTeeShape)
>   contains all the formatting properties (Brush, Pen, Font, etc) to
>   display the hint.

Since TeeChart ActiveX is a wrapper from TeeChart VCL, you can use this new feature from TeeChart ActiveX v2014.0.0.1.
So you just have to keep in mind to set `SystemHints` to False if you want to use the TeeShape properties. Here it is a simple example:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False

  TChart1.AddSeries scBar
  TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues

  TChart1.Tools.Add tcMarksTip
  TChart1.Tools.Items(0).asMarksTip.Format.Picture.LoadImage "C:\tmp\ImageForAllValues.jpg"
  TChart1.Tools.Items(0).asMarksTip.SystemHints = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Yeray, Actually new TChart Control have option of Image Picture in Mark Tips Tool can we use this for the same if so please help me in this if possible.

Comment: Hi Yeray, I have implemented using the Rectangle Tool. Just want to know how can I add a callout. Below is the code which I have added but Arrow is not drawn. Only a Dot appears at (0,0).m_ctrlChart.GetTools().GetItems(0).GetAsRectangle().GetCallout().SetVisible(TRUE);
    m_ctrlChart.GetTools().GetItems(0).GetAsRectangle().GetCallout().GetBrush().SetColor(RGB(255,0,0));
    m_ctrlChart.GetTools().GetItems(0).GetAsRectangle().GetCallout().GetPen().SetColor(RGB(0,0,255)); m_ctrlChart.GetTools().GetItems(0).GetAsRectangle().GetCallout().GetArrow().SetColor(RGB(0,255,0));

Comment: I'll better answer you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301069/callout-in-rectangle-tool