# Callout in Rectangle tool

Tags: activex, teechart

Just want to know how can I add a callout to Rectangle tool. Below is the code which I have added but Arrow is not drawn. Only a Dot appears at (0,0).

m_ctrlChart.GetTools().GetItems(0).GetAsRectangle().GetCallout().SetVisibl‌​e(TRUE); m_ctrlChart.GetTools().GetItems(0).GetAsRectangle().GetCallout().GetBrush().SetC‌​olor(RGB(255,0,0)); m_ctrlChart.GetTools().GetItems(0).GetAsRectangle().GetCallout().GetPen().SetCol‌​or(RGB(0,0,255)); m_ctrlChart.GetTools().GetItems(0).GetAsRectangle().GetCallout().GetArrow().SetC‌​olor(RGB(0,255,0));

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the property you are looking for is `Callout.Arrow.Visible`:

```
m_ctrlChart.GetTools().GetItems(0).GetAsRectangle().GetCallout().GetArrow().SetVisible(TRUE);
```

`GetCallout().SetVisibl‌​e(TRUE)` is for the Pointer